# GlGenTextures keeps returing 0's

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm trying to generate textures like so:

```
#define checkImageWidth 64
#define checkImageHeight 64
static GLubyte checkImage[checkImageHeight][checkImageWidth][4];
static GLubyte otherImage[checkImageHeight][checkImageWidth][4];

static GLuint texName[2];

void makeCheckImages(void)
{
    int i, j, c;

    for (i = 0; i < checkImageHeight; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < checkImageWidth; j++) {
            c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8))==0))*255;
            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) 255;
            c = ((((i&0x10)==0)^((j&0x10))==0))*255;
            otherImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
            otherImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) 0;
            otherImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) 0;
            otherImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) 255;
        }
    }
}
void init(void)
{    
    glClearColor (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    makeCheckImages();
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glGenTextures(2, texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, checkImageWidth,
        checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        checkImage);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);   
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, checkImageWidth, 
        checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
        otherImage);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    engineGL.current.tex = texName[1];
}
```

But when I check the values of texName[0] and [1] they are both 0, I do not understand why, what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the only function that fails?

Comment: No, other things are failing too, I'm calling init() after setting up my context...

Comment: have you verified that you're succeeding in setting up your context?

Comment: If other functions are failing too, then write the shortest code snippet you can in which a function fails, so you can narrow down where the error is introduced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try calling `glGetError`. It should tell you in more detail what went wrong. In general, if an OpenGL function fails, the first thing you do should be to ask OpenGL why it failed. It knows, because it just tried to execute the function.

It's much harder for us to guess at what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Use `gluErrorString()` to find out. :) http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#glGetError_.28or_.22How_do_I_check_for_GL_errors.3F.29

Comment: The (documentation)[http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml] mentiones that "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glGenTextures is executed between the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.". Does that help you?

Comment: Yea I had seen this but I don't do any sort of rendering before calling init() so im confused.

Answer (score 24):

You probably are calling glGenTextures before creating the OpenGL context, and that will generate a GL error. Don't try to create textures before you've initialized OpenGL.

Comment: Yes, that was 1 of my issues, I was also calling wglmakecurrent in my render loop which was causing trouble

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem, and `glGetError()` was returning 0.

In my case it was caused by calling `glGenTextures(...)` on a different thread to the one the GL context was created on (because I was loading the textures asynchronously).  Calling it from the main thread *after* the async load made `glGenTextures(...)` start working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was "lazy loading" my texture, so the glGenTexture was inside a glBegin / glEnd command !

Answer (score 0):

before calling glGenTexture, your opengl context must be created and XXXMakeCurrent'ed